# Windows Remote Desktop Will not Connect Over Internet Even Though Port is Open

Tags: remote-desktop

Have a remote access terminal laptop that is intended to provide temporary remote access to some equipment during a commissioning process.  Need to be able to remote into it from several states away for a period of 1-2 months.

I set up windows remote desktop on the new terminal laptop and tested it with the laptop on my LAN, and it works fine on my LAN.

Then I moved the the terminal over to the cellular hotspot that will be used, so now it is no longer local to my LAN.  Port forwarding is set up in the hotspot and I am using the public IP of the cellular network.  WRD will not connect.

I have confirmed the port is open;  NMAP shows it open and listening, and Port Forward Tester also sees it open from outside of my network as well.    And yet, it does not work.  But it works fine when its inside my LAN.

What are the next steps in troubleshooting?

[image: port forward test results]